# SELECT 2 tables (no join) using LINQ

Tags: sql, linq

I have 2 tables MaxDates and MinDates, each with a single DateTime column. I can write the following  database SELECT query with the goal of creating a data set that includes all combinations of min and max dates (to calculate time spans):

```
SELECT MinDates.PriceDate, MaxDates.PriceDate
FROM MinDates, MaxDates
```

I'm new to LINQ and wanted to create the LINQ equivalent. I thought the following would be a good starting point but no luck.

```
var result = from MaxDates, MinDates 
             select MaxDates.PriceDate, MinDates.PriceDate
```

Any thoughts on what the equivalent LINQ statement would be and is this a good use for LINQ (vs just doing this using some arrays)?

Comment: beware, the query produces cartesian product

Comment: Please note that what you are talking about *is a join*.  The fact that you are not using the word `JOIN` doesn't change that.

Comment: Thanks everyone for your comments and corrections. By making some name changes I was able to implement the approach suggested by D Stanley and others.

Answer (score 2):

You're close :

```
var result = from max in MaxDates
             from min in MinDates 
             select new {MaxDate = max.PriceDate, MinDate = min.PriceDate};
```

This will give you the cartesian product (CROSS JOIN) you're looking for.

Answer (score 2):

cartesian product (or CROSS JOIN in an SQL world) in linq is :

```
var crossResult = from max in MaxDates
                  from min in MinDates
                  select new { maxPriceDate = max.PriceDate, minPriceDate = min.PriceDate};
```

Comment: This will not compile becuase the two fields of your anonymous type have the same name (`PriceDate`)

Answer (score 1):

```
var res = from max in MaxDates
                  from min in MinDates
                  select new { MaxPriceDate = max.PriceDate,
                               MinPriceDate = min.PriceDate};
```

Comment: This will not compile becuase the two fields of your anonymous type have the same name (`PriceDate`)

Answer (score 0):

By using extension method,

```
var results = MaxDates.SelectMany(x => MinDates, (x, y) => new {x, y});
```